# Is there a way to have different guest customer groups, switchable through UI?

Tags: php, magento

I want guests of my Magento shop to be able to switch between two simple states:

- full price of products (group Guest1)
- prices without tax, maybe some special prices (group Guest2)

Is it possible to have some dropdown in the shop to switch between the two groups, without being logged in?

The order will later be checked whether the prices of Guest2 apply to the customer, but I would like to show them beforehand, what the prices would look like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento uses the NOT_LOGGED_IN customer group, which is a constant in the code.

To change the constant, change the line 418 in `app/code/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php` from

```
$customerTaxClass = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getTaxClassId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
```

to

```
$customerTaxClass = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getTaxClassId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId());
```

Now anywhere in the code, the customer group of the not logged in user can be changed with the following code:

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn())
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerGroupId(2);
```

Comment: I do have a similar requirement(in m1 & m2 both), did it worked for you, or if you might made any other changes or just have restored/rolled back.

Comment: @GunJanMehta back then it worked this way, but I cannot guarantee that things didn't change in newer versions of Magento in the last 6 years.